# How to get data from two MySQL tables using hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

In my database I have two tables `airport` and `calendar` connected by foreight key `airport_id`. I want to get json response with data from two tables for the determined `airport_id=273`

[image]

For example I want to get data for Airport with `airport_id` and Calendar with foreight key `airport_id` equels 273. Actually, I've got empty response from localhost:8080. I didn't get any error, just a blank page, like on the picture below. What I do wrong? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Airport.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "airport")
public class Airport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer airport_id;

    @Column(name = "departureAirport")
    private String departureAirport;

    @Column(name = "destinationAirport")
    private String destinationAirport;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "airport")
    @JsonManagedReference("airport")
    private List<Calendar> calendars; ....
```

Calendar.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "calendar")
public class Calendar {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer calendar_id;

@Column(name = "departureTime")
private Time departureTime;

@Column(name = "destinationTime")
private Time destinationTime;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Airport.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "airport_id")
@JsonBackReference("airport")
private Airport airport; ....
```

CalendarController.java

```
public class CalendarController {

@Autowired
CalendarService calendarService;

@Autowired
AirportService airportService;

@GetMapping(value = "/search/{airport_id}")
public List<Calendar> getCalendars(@PathVariable("airport_id") Integer airport_id) {
    Airport airport = airportService.findOne(airport_id);
    return calendarService.findOne(airport);
}}
```

CalendarRepository.java

```
 public interface CalendarRepository extends CrudRepository<Calendar, Integer> {

 Calendar getOne(int calendar_id);
 List<Calendar> findByAirport(Airport airport_id);
 }
```

CalendarService.java

```
public interface CalendarService {

List<Calendar> findOne(Airport airport_id);
}
```

CalendarServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class CalendarServiceImpl implements CalendarService {

@Autowired
CalendarRepository repository;

@Autowired
AirportRepository airportRepository;

@Override
public List<Calendar> getCalendars(Integer airport_id) {
    Airport airport = airportRepository.getOne(airport_id);
    return repository.findByAirport(airport);
}}
```

**Update**

AirpostService.java

```
public interface AirportService {

Airport findOne(int airport_id);
}
```

AirportRepository.java

```
public interface AirportRepository extends CrudRepository<Airport, Integer> {

Airport getOne(Integer airport_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your Hibernate, but your Controller. You just need to add the `@Responsebody` annotation to your method. The `@ResponseBody` annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/search/{airport_id}")
@ResponseBody
public List<Calendar> getCalendars(@PathVariable("airport_id") Integer airport_id) {
    Airport airport = airportService.findOne(airport_id);
    return calendarService.findOne(airport);
}}
```

Comment: unfortunately, nothing has changed

Comment: Could you post your Repository's code? Maybe you are returning an empty list, because otherwise, it should work.

Comment: I meant the code for the AirportRepository's implementation. Just to rule that one out. Also, when you debug your code, is `calendarService.findOne(airport)` returning an empty list?